# Laravel get relation from softdelete

Tags: php, laravel, soft-delete

I've got 2 tables,

```
user
intern
```

A user `belongsTo` a intern, and a inter `hasOne` user. My problem is that when I've softdelete a `user` record and the related `intern` record. And I want to restore it i can't find the related intern anymore.

So when I find the user like this:

```
$user = user::onlyTrashed()->find($userId);
```

And then say `$user->intern` result is null because it cannot find `intern`

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

How could I fix this?

Comment: Does every single trashed user definitely have an intern? do you have a soft delete column on both tables?

Comment: Yes I've that's not the problem.

Comment: Which question was that an answer too?

Comment: To both questions.

Comment: In that case you might need to do `$user->intern->withTrashed()`; as your intern table also has softdeletes.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the user exists. If does, do whatever you want to do.

Here's the code

```
$user = user::onlyTrashed()->find($userId);

if(!is_null($user)) {
  echo $user->intern;
} else {
  echo 'User does not exist!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the soft deleted `intern` object from your user object, try the following:

```
$user->intern()->withTrashed()->get()->first()
```